# MIPS assembly language - Calling a funcion without the use of 'jal'

Tags: assembly, mips, function-call

I want to call a function but for some reasons I'm now allowed to use the 
`jal` instruction. Is there a way to do that?

An idea I had was to somehow get the value of the Program Counter in `$ra`
and then just use `j function`, so something like this

```
                   # somehow $ra = address of next instruction
addi $ra, $ra, 8   # word length is 32 bytes so $ra gets the address of 
                   # the next instruction after 'j function'
j function
                   # continue here after function ends

function:
    # do stuff
    jr $ra
```

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

If you look up the behavior of the `jal` instruction in any reference, it is trivial to emulate it. You probably know it anyway that `jal` stores the return address in `$ra`, which is why you can return from functions using `jr $ra`. Thus, all you need to do is store that address yourself and then you can use `j`. For example:

```
    la $ra, continue
    j function
continue:
    ...
```

Comment: Or load a register with the target address and use `jalr`. Anyone placing unreasonable restrictions on instruction use should at least be thorough.